# Split graph into two parts according to min-cut between s and t vertices

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I am implementing min-cut graph clustering, and I need to be able to split a
graph into two parts **S** and **T** according to the st min-cut I build on each clustering step for some **s** and **t** vertices. Basically, I want to have a function which takes a graph **G**, a node **s**, and a node **t** and returns two disjoint sets of nodes **S** and **T**.

To the best of my knowledge, the easiest way to find an st min-cut is via exploiting min-cut ~ max-flow duality and using *Push-relabel algorithm* for max-flow calculation. But the push-relabel algorithm doesn't give us any information on what **S** and **T** sets are.

So, what is the right way to get **S** and **T** min-cut subsets? Is there a way to use Push-relabel algorithm? Is there an implementation of this in C++ or Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the information computed by the push-relabel algorithm to determine a min-cut.
As you know, the push-relabel algorithm assigns a value *h(v)* for each vertex *v*. The possible values of *h(v)* are in the interval [0,N], where N is the number of vertices of the graph. It's easy to prove that there exists some number *h'* such that *h(v) != h'* for every vertex *v* (see exercise 26.4-3 of Cormen's book, 2nd Ed). After finding such *h'*, every vertex *v* with *h(v) < h'* is in one side of the cut, and every vertex *u* with *h(u) > h'* is in the other side.